# Are the roots of unity the only algebraic subgroups of the multiplicative group?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

$\newcommand{\G}{\mathbb{G}}$
Let $k$ a field (or maybe more generally an arbitrary ring with connected spectrum), $\G_m$ the multiplicative group over $k$. Are the $\mu_n = \{x^n = 1\}$ the only $k$-subgroup schemes of $\G_m$? What is the best way to see this? I have difficulty mostly in the algebraically closed field case.

**My incomplete thoughts:**

Working first on $\overline{k}$ an algebraically closed field, a proper closed subgroup-scheme $H$ of $\G_m$ must be affine of dimension zero, hence its $\overline{k}$-points are a finite discrete subgroup of $\overline{k}^\times$ and must coincide with $\mu_n$ for some $n$ (WLOG relatively prime to $p$, the characteristic).

How do I know there aren't any choices for nonreduced structure to put on these sets of points other than the ones which define $\mu_{np^k}$?

Edit: I suppose by homogeneity that the nonreduced structure on each point must be identical to that on the identity, so we reduce to classifying subgroups of $\G_m$ supported on the origin. Perhaps this can be approached ring-theoretically?

How do you descend the case above to $k_s$, so that Galois descent gives the case of an arbitrary field? The proof above doesn't seem to translate so well, as we could have to worry about $H$ being supported on points which aren't $k_s$-rational. But $k_s \to \overline{k}$ is a universal homeomorphism, so maybe one can sidestep the issue somehow?

I don't know how one would formally patch this result to arbitrary rings or schemes, but it seems intuitively true since the classification is uniform and discrete (so it doesn't seem like a subgroup could vary in families except to be constant.)

Comment: I'm just wondering whether the Frobenius kernels would qualify. They have been used heavily in the representation theory of characteristic $p$ algebraic groups. Largely as substitutes for Lie algebras. I have become rather rusty with this, but the idea is (IIRC) to take the scheme theoretic kernel of the Frobenius automorphism. Of course, the resulting group scheme won't have any non-trivial rational point over any field, but the structure sheaf is different. If you think of an algebraic group scheme over a field $k$ as a functor from commutative $k$-algebras to groups, you see extra points.

Comment: (cont'd) After all, when you look at a $k$-algebra with nilpotent elements, you get non-trivial points mapped to the identity by the Frobenius. Somewhat analogous to the Lie group - Lie algebra situation, where you get a quick idea of the Lie algebra of a Lie group of matrices by checking out which matrices of the form $I+\epsilon A$ (with $\epsilon^2=0$) satisfy the defining equations of the Lie group.

Comment: In your case of the multiplicative group scheme (as opposed to, say $SL_n(k)$) you would then also see the groups $\mu_n$ thickened by a Frobenius kernel.

Comment: What you've written can't be literally true -- what do you mean by subgroup scheme? Do you at least want to assume that it's flat and finite presentation over the base?

Comment: If you assume that $H\subseteq \mathbb{G}_{m,S}$ is flat and of finite presentation over $S$ then it's true.

Comment: @Jyrki As Alex confirmed in a comment below, the relative Frobenius for the multiplicative group is the $p$-th power map, so has kernel $\mu_p$, so this doesn't seem to introduce any new possibilities.

Comment: LOL, a fair point C.D. :-) What the Frobenius kernels bring to us is then surely covered in the scheme theoretic version of $\mu_n$. It, too, has those extra points when the functor is applied to a $k$-algebra with nilpotent elements. Sorry about creating some confusion.

Comment: C.D. I don't know if you get pinged for edits, but I just wanted to let you know I added an example of why flatness is important.

Comment: Yes, I saw it! Thanks for the clarification and reorganization -- it seems evident now that without flatness of course one should have to worry about fibers jumping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Case of fields

Let me begin by confirming your suspicion over a field.

> **Claim (field case):** *Let $k$ be a field, and $H\subsetneq \mathbf{G}_{m,k}$. Then, $H$ is isomorphic to $\mu_{n,k}$ for some $n\in\mathbf{Z}_{\geqslant 1}$.*

As the later answer uses more heavily the theory of multiplicative group schemes, let me sketch a proof of this using more the theory of finite group schemes.

*Proof:* If $k$ has characteristic $0$ then this is trivial. Indeed, in this case $H$ is etale by [Pink, Theorem 13.2]. Then, by [Pink, Theorem 12.2] we know that it suffices to show that $H(\overline{k})$ agrees with $\mu_N(\overline{k})$ as $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$-modules for some $N$. But, as $H(\overline{k})$ is a $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$-submodule of $\overline{k}^\times$ this is clear.

So, we may assume that $\mathrm{char}(k)=p>0$. As we have the connected-etale sequence

$$1\to H^\circ\to H\to \pi_0(H)\to 1,$$

(see [Milne, Proposition 5.58]), where $H^\circ$ is connected and $\pi_0(H)$ is etale, it suffices to show that $H^\circ=\mu_{p^r,k}$ for some $r$ and that $\pi_0(H)=\mu_{N,k}$ for some $p\nmid N$. Indeed, in this case, the connected-etale sequence necessarily splits by a simple computation (e.g. see [Milne, Corollary 15.40]), and as $H$ is commutative the claim will follow.

So, let us first assume that $H$ is etale. Then, the argument works exactly as in the characteristic $0$ case noting that the finite $\mathrm{Gal}(k^\mathrm{sep}/k)$-submodules of $(k^\mathrm{sep})^\times$ are of the form $\mu_N(k^\mathrm{sep})$ for some $p\nmid N$.

So, let us assume that $H$ is connected. Note then that the relative Frobenius map $F_H$ on $H$ is nilpotent (e.g. see [Pink, Proposition 15.6]), say $F_H^\ell=0$. Since $H\subseteq \mathbf{G}_{m,k}$ we see that this implies that $H\subseteq \ker(F_{\mathbf{G}_{m,k}}^\ell)=\mu_{p^\ell,k}$. But, we then see that $H\subseteq \mu_{p^\ell,k}$ gives us (by Cartier duality) a surjection $\underline{\mathbf{Z}/p^\ell\mathbf{Z}}_k\cong \mu_{p^\ell,k}^\vee\twoheadrightarrow H^\vee$. It's easy to see then that this implies that $H^\vee \cong \underline{\mathbf{Z}/p^r\mathbf{Z}}_k$ for some $r$, and so $H\cong H^{\vee\vee}\cong \mu_{p^r,k}$. $\blacksquare$

---

### Issue with claim over arbitrary base

Unfortunately, the claim as stated is false over arbitrary base. In fact, we can write down a very simple example.

Let $R$ be a DVR with uniformizer $\pi$ (e.g. $R=\mathbf{Z}_p$ and $\pi=p$, or $R=\mathbf{C}[\![t]\!]$ and $\pi=t$) and consider

$$H:=V(\pi x^r-\pi)\subseteq \mathbf{G}_{m,R}=\mathrm{Spec}(R[x^{\pm 1}]).$$

Then, it's easy to see that

$$H_{R[\pi^{-1}]}\cong \mu_{r,R[\pi^{-1}]},\qquad H_{R/\pi R}\cong \mathbf{G}_{m,R/\pi R}.$$

In particular, $H\subseteq \mathbf{G}_{m,R}$, but $H$ is not isomorphic to $\mu_{n,R}$ for some $n$.

This group $H$ may look artificial, but it is in fact not. For example, let us consider the action

$$\mathbf{G}_{m,R}\times\mathrm{GL}_{2,R}\to\mathrm{GL}_{2,R},\qquad \left(x,\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\right)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x^r & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x^r & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

Then,

$$H=\mathrm{Cent}\left(\mathbf{G}_{m,R},\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & \pi\\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right).$$

Fix a base scheme $S$ and $H\subsetneq\mathbf{G}_{m,S}$. By the field case discussed above, for every point $s$ of $S$ the subgroup $H_s\subseteq \mathbf{G}_{m,k(s)}$ is $\mu_{n_s,k(s)}$ for some $n_s\in\mathbf{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$ (where we take the convention that $\mu_{0,k(s)}:=\mathbf{G}_{m,k(s)}$). The issue is that there's no guarantee, as we saw in the above example, that the function

$$n\colon |S|\to\mathbf{Z}_{\geqslant 0},\qquad s\mapsto n_s,$$

is constant.

*Challenge question:* For $R$ as above, can you describe which functions $n\colon |\mathrm{Spec}(R)|\to \mathbf{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$ are actually realized by some $H\subsetneq \mathbf{G}_{m,R}$? Can you describe matrix realizations of the groups you construct?

---

### The case of general base

To remedy the issue that $n_s$ is constant, one should imagine that we need $H\to S$ to have 'continuously varying fibers'. If you've been in the game long enough, you know that is code for 'flat'. Fore sxample, our example above is not flat as the map $R[x^{\pm 1}]/(\pi x^r-\pi)$ has $\pi$-torsion.

To state the result correctly, let us fix a base scheme $S$ and recall that a group $S$-scheme $H\to S$ is *fppf* if it is flat and locally of finite presentation. For simplicity let us assume that $S$ is locally Noetherian.${}^{\color{red}{(1)}}$

> **Claim (general base):** *If $H\subsetneq \mathbf{G}_{m,S}$ is an fppf group $S$-scheme, then $H$ is isomorphic to $\mu_{n,S}$ for some $n$.*

*Proof:* Let us observe that as $H$ is fppf over $S$ that [Conrad, Corollary B.3.3] implies that $H\to S$ is of multiplicative type as in Definition B.1.1 of loc. cit. But, if $\xi\colon \text{Spec}(\Omega)\to S$ is a geometric point, then by[SGA 3, Exposé X, Théorème 7.1] there is an anti-equivalence of categories between group $S$-schemes of multiplicative type and discrete $\pi_1^\text{SGA3}(S,\xi)$-modules${}^{\color{red}{(2)}}$ finitely generated as an abelian group given by
$$H\mapsto X(H,\xi):= \text{Hom}_\Omega(H_\xi, \mathbf{G}_{m,\xi}).$$
In particular, from our closed embedding of group $S$-schemes $H\hookrightarrow \mathbf{G}_{m,S}$ we get a closed embedding of group $\Omega$-schemes $H_\xi\hookrightarrow\mathbf{G}_{m,\xi}$ which induces a surjection $X(\mathbf{G}_{m,S},\xi)\to X(H,\xi)$ which is evidently $\pi_1^\text{SGA3}(S,\xi)$-equivariant. But, $X(\mathbf{G}_{m,S},\xi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$ with the trivial $\pi_1^\text{SGA3}(S,\xi)$-action. Thus, the surjection $X(\mathbf{G}_{m,S},\xi)\to X(H,\xi)$, which can't be an isomorphism as we assumed that $H\to \mathbf{G}_{m,S}$ was not an isomorphism, identifies $X(H,\xi)$ as $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ with the trivial $\pi_1^\text{SGA3}(S,\xi)$-action for some $n$. But, it's easy to compute that this is precisely $X(\mu_{n,S},\xi)$, and so the claim follows. $\blacksquare$

$\color{red}{(1)}$: That said, it should almost certainly be ok for locally topologically Noetherian $S$, and probably in general by a `descent to the Noetherian case' type argument. For instance, if $S$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated then one quickly reduces to the Noetherian case by combining [Tag 01ZA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZA) and [Tag 01ZM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZM).

$\color{red}{(2)}$: The topological group $\pi_1^\text{SGA3}(S,\xi)$ is an enlargement of the etale fundamental group $\pi_1^\text{et}(S,\xi)$ first studied in [SGA3, Exposé X, §6]. This group has its category of discrete sets with continuous action classifies the category $\mathbf{ULoc}(S_\text{et})$ -- the category of 'disjoint unions of' sheaves of sets on $S_\text{et}$ locally constant for the etale topology -- this is contrast to $\pi_1^\text{et}(S,\xi)$ whose category of discrete sets with continuoussets classifies $\mathbf{ULCC}(S_\text{et})$ -- the category of 'disjoint unions of' sheaves of sets on $S_\text{et}$ which are locally constant for the etale topology with finite fibers. The two groups actually coincide when $S$ is normal. You can also understand this as the maximal pro-discrete quotient of the pro-etale fundamental group from [BS].

**References:**

[BS] Bhatt, B. and Scholze, P., 2013. The pro-'etale topology for schemes. arXiv preprint arXiv:1309.1198.

[Conrad]Conrad, B., 2014. Reductive group schemes. Autour des schémas en groupes, 1(93-444), p.23.

[Milne] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.

[Pink] [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~pink/ftp/FGS/CompleteNotes.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Epink/ftp/FGS/CompleteNotes.pdf)

[SGA3] M. Demazure, A. Grothendieck, Sch´emas en groupes I, II, III, Lecture Notes in Math 151, 152, 153, Springer-Verlag, New York (1970).

Comment: What does "finite" mean in the phrase "finite discrete $\pi_1$-modules" if $\mathbb{Z}$ is an example? Finitely generated?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not going to try to follow this argument over a base scheme more complicated than $\text{Spec}$ of a field; in that case I'm familiar with the classification of group schemes of multiplicative type in terms of Galois actions but I don't know why an fppf subgroup scheme of $\mathbb{G}_m$ must have multiplicative type (in particular I don't know how to rule out the possibility of non-reduced behavior as the OP and Jyrki have been speculating about, especially in the positive characteristic case). Do the results you're quoting simplify enough in this case to give a direct proof?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am unfortunately not sure I understand Jyrki's idea -- the relative Frobenius map for the multiplicative group has kernel $\mu_p$, right? Anyways, another way to think about multiplicative groups are those that are geometrically 'diagonalizable' (i.e. isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(k[M])$ for some finitely generated abelian group $M$ with the obvious group scheme structure). So, it suffices to show that a subgroup of a diagonalizable group is diagonalizable. That said, you can phrase diagonalizable groups as being those whose global sections are generated by group-like elements

Comment: using this it's easy/elementary to show the claim. For example, see Theorem 4.4 (c) of Chapter XIV here: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf Let me know if that clears things up.

Comment: Okay, it looks like I'm missing something very basic. It looks like for Milne (affine) subgroup schemes are closed by definition? That makes things very straightforward as you say, but then why is there a concept of open subgroup scheme? Actually I guess I have no idea what a "subscheme" is, generally. Gun to my head I'd define a "subgroup scheme" as a morphism $f : G \to H$ of group schemes which is injective on functors of points; is such a thing necessarily a closed affine subgroup scheme if $H$ is an affine group scheme?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm not sure what you mean. Open subgroup schemes are not really a thing. For example, over a field any homomorphism of linear algebraic groups $G\to H$ with trivial kernel is a closed immersion (e.g. see Prop 1.1.1 of this: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf) -- results like this hold over more general bases.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan By the way, it's true that every homomorphism of linear algebaric groups over a field has closed image. This is, in the case of a monomorphism, a priori weaker than saying it's a closed immersion, but it's a general fact I thought you might want to know.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't know if it's more your style, but I have included a proof now that is more specific to fields.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's helpful.